# No such device or address when using sendto() with a raw socket

Tags: c, networking, raw-sockets

I created the socket `socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL));` then i used the structure `sockaddr_ll` so i could give me sendto method a address and interface. But when i try to send a packet i get a "No such device or address" message. Any idea of what it means? I've been searching quite a lot and i can't seem to find anything useful!
I used a debugger to see if i was getting the wrong interface number but i think it is correct. I also tried to change some parameters of the sockaddr_ll and the sock itself but nothing works.

Comment: I don't see any code that doesn't work. Where is the minimal code that doesn't work?

Comment: i get the error in this part 
`sendto(sockfd, dst_ptr, dst_msg_size, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll))`

Comment: Okay, so where is the code that doesn't work? I still don't see it. When I run the code you said, it tells me that dst_ptr and dst_msg_size and socket_address are undefined. Is that the error you get? You need to define those variables.

Comment: The error was in the interface number that i give to the socket (the ioctl functions don't work that well). I used the `if_nametoindex()` and then it worked fine

Comment: Warning: You may need to run your program with sudo